# Java: Understanding Preferences

Tags: java, preferences

So I started using `Preferences` for the first time. For example:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            pref.put("LAST_WIDTH", "" + frame.getWidth());
            pref.put("LAST_HEIGHT", "" + frame.getHeight());
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

I encountered a problem when launching the application for the first time when I try to retrieve the last size.

```
if(pref.get("LAST_WIDTH", "") != null && pref.get("LAST_HEIGHT", "") != null){
        try{
            frame.setSize(Integer.parseInt(pref.get("LAST_WIDTH", "")), Integer.parseInt(pref.get("LAST_HEIGHT", "")));
        } catch(NumberFormatException e){
            frame.setSize(640, 480);
        }
    } else{
        frame.setSize(640, 480);
    }
```

Yes, I found a workaround with the try-catch, but I'd like to understand how preferences work. If I launch an application for the first time and try to retrieve a key that should not exist, what does preferences return?

Operating system is Windows 7 if that matters.

Comment: By the way never be satisfied by this kind of solution where you catch an exception that is not supposed to be caught

Comment: @Dici I am not satisfied, and the answer provided showed me how to do it properly.

Comment: @Dici, at least he problem solved, and made it work. :D

Comment: @MattClark nope, it's a very bad practice to ignore programming errors and even worse to try to recover from them. Most of the times unchecked exceptions are not supposed to be caught, they should make the program fail.

Comment: @MeikVtune yep I know, I'm just stressing how important it is to favor th *right* solution over the first crap that works. You did a good joob at coming here to improve the code :)

Comment: @Dici I'd love to post my whole application here for review to improve, but I don't think this is the right platform to do so :)

Comment: @MeikVtune there's a StackOverflow website for code reviews. Otherwise, if your project is not too huge I'm happy to give comments. I love reading and improving code :p

Comment: @Mat'sMug I was proposing to review myself, that's why I preferred a small project :p And yes I know SO is *this* site but I wasn't sure of the company name and was too lazy to look for it ^^

Comment: @Mat'sMug Could it be that CR's 'tour' is not made for CR? I was very confused when I read the "Do not ask" section and found "Tools, improving, or conducting code reviews".

Comment: @MeikVtune the website is for giving and receiving reviews, not for asking about tools enabling to conduct reviews. It's like on StackOverflow, we don't take questions such as *What is the best library for... ? What is the best language for... ?**

Comment: That's actually correct - questions about tools for reviewing code are indeed off-topic. I believe the `/on-topic` page is clearer, but the best way to understand CR is on meta - see [a guide to CR for SO users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777/23788), and [how to get the best value out of CR](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436/23788) in particular. Of course you can always hop into [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) and ask anything site-related to the regulars =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using it right in your example!

```
String a = pref.get("key", "defaultValue");
```

[From the docs:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html#get(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

> Parameters:
>       key - key whose associated value is to be returned.
>       def - the value to be returned in the event that this preference node has no value associated with key.

So in your case, replace the empty strings with your default values.

```
frame.setSize(Integer.parseInt(pref.get("LAST_WIDTH", "640")), Integer.parseInt(pref.get("LAST_HEIGHT", "480")));
```

Comment: Thank you! I totally overlooked the second argument as a possible solution(stupid me did not properly check the JavaDoc for `get`)